# iOS bug? (23/24 August)

Tags: discussion, bug, status-completed

Main and meta are nearly impossible to navigate.

The "view full site" option isn't registering.

I see this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/oMtap.jpg

(note that the alignment is way off)

Anyone else??

Now I will add a sentence to meet quality standards.  Well, that didn't work. $2+2=3$

Comment: For sufficiently large values of 3.

Comment: In a ring with one element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[The issue has been resolved](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/144693/my-ipad-started-showing-the-mobile-version). If this question and answer are found to be of no use, feel free to delete without notifying me.